# Add image source from StorageFile UWP

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, storage, readfile

I'm trying to add image source from Storage Folder. First I capture photo and save it to the Storage Folder

```
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        private async void btnPhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            // Create the file that we're going to save the photo to.
        var file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

        // Update the file with the contents of the photograph.         

        await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), file);
    }
```

At the next Page I should get the photo from cache, but I have an exception, when I'm creating sampleFile

```
        public async void GetImage()
    {

        string filename = "sample.jpg";
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = 
            await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFileAsync(filename); // Here I have exception {"Access is denied.\r\n"} System.UnauthoriziedAccessException


        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        img = await LoadImage(sampleFile);

        image1.Source = img;
    }


    private static async Task<BitmapImage> LoadImage(StorageFile file)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        FileRandomAccessStream stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);

        return bitmapImage;
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong? And how can I get access to Storage Folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the document library unless the user allows you to do that. You can specify document library access in the manifest, but only for certain files, and such app will probably never be published in the Windows Store unless it REALLY requires that access as stated by Microsoft. As you are using .jpg files you have Pictures library for that, and you can specify it in the manifest and everything will work just fine.

Otherwise you get access by file picker, storing the token to recall it later.